# Difference between Immutable.js List() and List.of()?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I'm reading through the Immutable.js docs for creating lists with `List()` and `List.of()` and I don't understand what the difference is. Any help with understanding this would be great.

Comment: `List` actually creates a list with `iterator` and `List.of()` creates `List` with individual values as @4castle has given the answer beautifully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`List.of()`](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/of) uses each parameter as a separate element in the created list, while [`List()`](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/List) takes a single parameter of some kind of iterable-like structure.

Usage:

```
List.of("a", "b", "c"); // ["a","b","c"]

List(["a","b","c"]); // ["a","b","c"]
```

The `...` notation in the definition `List.of<T>(...values: T[]): List<T>` is meant to indicate a variable number of arguments, which will be treated like an array internally, probably using the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) or a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).